# Datatrigger not firing after some call

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel, dependency-properties, datatrigger

It seems that this DataTrigger who doesn't fire is recurrent, unfortunately, I didn't found any answer for my problem.
I use a Dependency Property to work on my window

- To close it
- To hide it
- To show it

Actions can be called directly from the Window itself, or from a NotifyIcon, thru a Publisher Pattern
Problem is : The call of the actions doesn't fire anything after a while (depending on the actions I made before).

For instance, if I first close the window->ok

If I hide the window, then show it (this both works), then close it-> Not ok, nothing happens.

The code in the window :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="WindowBehaviourStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CloseSignal}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Behaviours:WindowBehaviour.Action" Value="Close"/>
            </DataTrigger>            
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HideSignal}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Behaviours:WindowBehaviour.Action" Value="Hide"/>
            </DataTrigger>       
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowSignal}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Behaviours:WindowBehaviour.Action" Value="Show"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

The code of the dependency Property :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ActionProperty =
                    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                    "Action",
                    typeof(BehaviourType),
                    typeof(WindowBehaviour),
                    new UIPropertyMetadata(BehaviourType.None,OnAction));

    private static void OnAction(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue is BehaviourType)
        {
            Window window = GetWindow(sender);
            BehaviourType behaviourType=((BehaviourType)e.NewValue);
            if (window != null)
            {
                if (behaviourType == BehaviourType.Close)
                    window.Close();
                else if (behaviourType == BehaviourType.Hide)
                    window.Hide();
                else if (behaviourType == BehaviourType.Show)
                    window.Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

I can say that the method "OnAction" is simply not called, when the problem occurs.

But I don't know (and I have no idea how to test it), if the problem comes from the call to the view, or from the call of ActionProperty.
Considering my research, it seems that I should reinit each time the Dependency Property, but I don't know how, and if this  is the problem, why can I still call twice the Dependency Property, then it doesn't work anymore?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Hi John, ok, sorry for that!